# django class view Overlapping

Tags: django, django-views

I am not good at English.
Please understand me.

I'm creating a blog  in Django.
I am making it into class view, but I want to see a reple list and form in the post details view.
like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4jpD.png)

POST detailview has already been implemented and I don't know how to add comments.
Should I be function view?

Give me some advice.

code

**views.py**

```
class BlogLV(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Blog

def get_queryset(self):
    return Blog.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user)

class BlogCV(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView): # blog_form.html
model = Blog
fields = ['name','description','image']
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')

def form_valid(self, form): #오류
    form.instance.user = self.request.user #user 설정
    form.instance.slug = self.request.user
    return super(BlogCV,self).form_valid(form)

class BlogDV(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
model = Blog

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
model = Post
fields = ['title', 'content']
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')
template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blog'] = Blog.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.slug = self.request.user
    return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

class PostDV(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
model = Post
fields =['title','content']

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDV, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blog'] = Blog.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context

class PostLV(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Post
paginate_by = 5

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostLV,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blog'] = Blog.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
model = Post
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDeleteView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blog'] = Blog.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context

class PostUV(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
model = Post
fields = ['title','content']
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostUV,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blog'] = Blog.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',BlogLV.as_view(),name="index"),
url(r'^create/$',BlogCV.as_view(),name='blog_create'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',BlogDV.as_view(),name='blog_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/post/create/$',PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post_create'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/post/$',PostLV.as_view(),name='post_list'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PostDV.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PostUV.as_view(), name='post_update'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
```

]

**models.py**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Blog(models.Model): # 유저 당 하나
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/profile')
create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,allow_unicode=True)
# 블로그 생성한 시각
# 저장 경로: MEDIA_ROOT/blog/projile/xxx.jpg 파일 저장
# DB 필드 'MEDIA_URL/blog/profile/xxx.jpg' 문자열 저장
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-create_date']
    # 생성된 날짜의 내림차순으로 정렬
def __str__(self):
    return self.name


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
content = models.TextField()
create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,default='slug')

class Meta :
    ordering = ['-create_date']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail',args=(self.id,))
# post.get_absolute_url args
# 객체가 지칭하는 url 반환
def get_previous_post(self):
    return self.get_previous_by_create_date()
#create_date 기준으로 이전 포스트 반환
# get_previous_by_column 내장객체 호출
def get_next_post(self):
    return self.get_next_by_create_date()

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Reple(models.Model):
content = models.TextField()
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
Post = models.IntegerField() # post_id
create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-create_date']
def __str__(self):
    return self.content
```

It's my first time writing, so I don't know how to Indent. Sorry
And if my code is not effective, tell me how to fix it.
thank you!

Comment: please share your current views, models, forms and also urls

Comment: Personally, i prefer to use function views, it gives me more control, but class based views is the new trend, it can save us a lot of time and effort, but you need to read the docs to get a clear idea how to do things, and how it cannot be done.

Comment: I revised the text. @Vipin Mohan R Nair

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to write the view from scratch as a function, but you can also override the existing post method to return additional data.

Comment: how?  what method?